# How to register dynamically created class file for @EnableJpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create wrapper for integrating multiple databases in spring boot.
In order to scan Repositories, i am creating Configuration class file annotated with @EnableJpaRepositories at runtime.

Steps :

1. Read multiple database configurations for some config file.
2. Create @Configuration class file  for each database at runtime
3. Register this configuration bean in spring boot at runtime.

Below is my code :

My dynamically created @Configuration class file at runtime from template looks something this :

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TESTDBJpaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver;

    @Bean("testdbdatasource")
    public DataSource clusterDataSource() throws Exception {
       
        // Initalizing datasource as per config value : say testDataSOurce    
        return testDataSOurce;
    }

    @Bean("testentitymanager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(clusterDataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        String packageName = ""; // package name picked from config
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(packageName);

        entityManagerFactory.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean("testtxnmanager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I am modifying the attributes of @EnableJpaRepositories at runtime and then registering the bean. Below is the code for that :

```
@Component
public class DatabasePostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        try {
                String generatedCode = "// Sample code for @COnfiguration class show above is this string"
                String className = "com.example.database.TESTDBJpaConfig";
                Class<?> generatedClass = InMemoryJavaCompiler.newInstance().compile(className, generatedCode);
                
                // Update @EnableJpaRepositories annotation with correct values
                updateJpaAnnotation(generatedClass);

                // register the bean here
                BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry )beanFactory);
                GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
                beanDefinition.setBeanClass(generatedClass);
                beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);
                beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);
                beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(className,beanDefinition);
                beanDefinition.getBeanClass().newInstance();

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            log.error("Unable to setup database");
        }
    }

    private void updateJpaAnnotation(Class<?> generatedClass) throws Exception {
        Method method = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("annotationData", null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object annotationData = method.invoke(generatedClass, null);
        Field declaredAnnotations = annotationData.getClass().getDeclaredField("declaredAnnotations");
        declaredAnnotations.setAccessible(true);
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> annotations = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) declaredAnnotations.get(annotationData);
        Annotation oldJpaAnnotation = annotations.get(EnableJpaRepositories.class);
        Annotation newJpaAnnotation = new EnableJpaRepositories(){
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return oldJpaAnnotation.annotationType();
            }
            @Override
            public String[] basePackages() {
                return // Base package from config;
            }
            @Override
            public String entityManagerFactoryRef() {
                return "testentitymanager";
            }

            @Override
            public String transactionManagerRef() {
                return "testtxnmanager";
            }
            // rest of the code
        };
        annotations.put(EnableJpaRepositories.class, newJpaAnnotation);
    }
}
```

Problem is : when i am running the code bean is getting registered, but code erros out when i @Autowire any repository class. It says "required a bean of type XYZ Repository not found".

Ideally when the bean is registered @EnableJpaRepositories with updated basePackages attribute it should have scanned them right ?

Please help me here, what am i doing wrong here

Comment: I wouldn't expect it. What makes you think you can change the metadata through modifying the map? If you are already generating the code why modify it afterwards, feels weird to me (although the whole construct feels weird to me but that is something else).